# How can I use Armadillo to compute eigenpairs?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, armadillo, eigenvalue

I just got Armadillo and wanted to familiarized myself so I am doing a "test" run with it

```
int main(){
    double myMatrix[6][6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            myMatrix[i][j] = i+2*j;
        }
    }

    mat ARMA_L;
    vec ARMA_eigenval;
    mat ARMA_eigenvec;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            ARMA_L(i,j) = myMatrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    eig_gen(ARMA_eigenval, ARMA_eigenvec, ARMA_L);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile, it says there's no function for call to eig_gen() 
but the documentation seems like I'm doing what I should be doing, however.

Comment: Do you have `#include <armadillo>`?

Comment: I did. I did include #include <armadillo> and using namespace arma and using namespace std; ..... etc

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong types for `eig_gen()` function. `ARMA_eigenval` and `ARMA_eigenvec` should be `cx_vec` and `cx_mat` respectively:

```
cx_vec ARMA_eigenval;
cx_mat ARMA_eigenvec;
```

See example in [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eig_gen):

```
mat A = randu<mat>(10,10);

cx_vec eigval;
cx_mat eigvec;

eig_gen(eigval, eigvec, A);
```

Comment: Even when I did change it to cx_vec and cx_mat, I got this weird compiling error    testing5.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6lapack4geevIdEEvPcS2_PiPT_S3_S5_S5_S5_S3_S5_S3_S5_S3_S3_[_ZN4arma6lapack4geevIdEEvPcS2_PiPT_S3_S5_S5_S5_S3_S5_S3_S5_S3_S3_]+0x8c): undefined reference to `dgeev_'

Comment: It is a linker error, not compiling error. You need to link with armadillo library like this: `g++  testing5.cpp -larmadillo`.

Comment: how can I link that on Dev-C++?